# How to create custom Spring Data JPA find method with my own property, specification and pageable?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to create my own custom Spring Data JPA find method that takes Integer, Specification and Pageable.

I've tried creating method like

```
Page<Student> findAllByGroupId(Integer id, Specification<Student> specification, Pageable pageable);
```

But it doesn't work.

User Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository<T extends User> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Integer>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
}
```

Student Repository

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends UserRepository<Student>{
    Page<Student> findAllByGroupId(Integer id, Specification<Student> specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Service

```
@Override
public Page<Student> getGroupStudents(Integer id, StudentQuery studentQuery, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<Student> specification =
            studentSpecification.getSpecification(studentQuery);

    return studentRepository.findAllByGroupId(id, specification, pageable);
}
```

When I try this I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.
```

Is there any way to create custom find method that takes Integer, Specification and Pageable?

Comment: Are you extending a PagingAndSortingRepository somewhere?

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Why do you need both a Specification and an Integer in this case? if the GroupId is an Integer, it can be Integer, Pageable.

Comment: I'd like to achieve something like this /api/classes/2/students?firstName=Foo

Comment: If you want to be able to filter on GroupID and other specifications, you should add the GroupId to the specification instead, and label the method as findAll(Specification, Pageable).